# Salesforce Rest API - Upsert Array records

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex-code

I want upsert an array Accounts with api standard. I have read that the composite can be used

```
PATCH /composite/sobjects/Account/MyExtId__c
{
    "allOrNone" : false,
    "records" : [{
        "attributes" : {"type" : "Account"},
        "Name" : "Company One",
        "MyExtId__c" : "AAA"
    }, {
        "attributes" : {"type" : "Account"},
        "Name" : "Company Two",
        "MyExtId__c" : "BBB"
    }]
}
```

Is it not possible to add a simple json like when integrating 1 single record?
For example:

```
PATCH /sobjects/Account/MyExtId__c
[
    {
        "Name" : "Company One",
        "MyExtId__c" : "AAA"
    },
    {
        "Name" : "Company Two",
        "MyExtId__c" : "BBB"
    }
]
```

Comment: Will you consider a rewrite to bulk API? It's different pattern, you wouldn't get the success messages synchronously. Upload the file, SF processes it asynchronously, you poll "is it done yet, is it done yet"? If you have thousands of records it could save you api calls, can take 10K records in 1 chunk... [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_preparing.htm](Bulk API works with XML, JSON, CSV). Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/14740/799 out? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk

Comment: The bulk api is not necessary, in the integration a maximum of 500 records will arrive. Is it not possible in the previously written form? It seems strange to me that it is possible with 1 record but not with an array

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, it's different message, object vs array... but that "records" variable is essentially array of your old objects and "all or none" is optional. See if it saves ok without `"attributes" : {"type" : "Account"}`?

Comment: this attribute is mandatory... OK thanks for the response :)